# Insert data after use 'delete' or 'truncate'

Tags: mysql

I have this two queries:

**Query 1:**

```
DELETE FROM table_2;
```

**Query 2:**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2
SELECT * from table_1;
```

Both queries work fine, running them separately does not give an error. But putting them together like this gives syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM table_2;
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2
SELECT * from table_1;

SQL Error: ... syntax error near 'INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2...
```

This error occurs because I can't use `INSERT` after a `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE`. I'm testing this in a scrypt before doing it in a stored procedure, how can I delete all the rows and then insert data? In case you suggest me to use `UPDATE`, what would your implementation look like?

EDIT SOLVED:

I was running the query in a scrypt, that's why it gave error. But if I put it in a stored procedure it doesn't give an error.

Comment: EVERY mysql statement needs to be terminated with semi-colon

Comment: how would it look? I put the semicolon like this `SELECT * from table_1; `, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: You were correct @P.Salmon , but in addition to missing the semicolons, I needed to put it inside a stored procedure, I was running it in a scrypt

Comment: Should work in a script and procedure see https://dbfiddle.uk/9lR1cFIN . If you publish script and procedure I will look again.